# putting condition on self.load function in knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is my view model:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable();
    self.error = ko.observable();
```

and these are my two loads functions:

```
self.reloadPosts = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: postApiUrl2,
            data: { id: $("#Locations").val() },
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
    }

    self.loadPosts = function () {
        // to load existing posts
        $.ajax({
            url: postApiUrl1,
          //  data: { id: $("#Locations").val() },
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'Get'
        })         
    }
self.loadPosts();
self.reloadPosts();
return self;
```

here, self.loadPosts is the function with no parameter in it and self.reloadPosts passes selected dropdown id to controller.

My question is-- is it possible to put condition here so that self.reloadPosts should only load data on the view page when it has some data.
Right now, both of these are loading one by one. i want to control it by some condition.this code is in .js file not on .cshtml page.

I am trying something like this but getting uncaught reference errror at first line:

```
  if (id != null) {
    self.reloadPosts();
}
else {
    self.loadPosts();
}
```

Can anyone suggest me something how to do it.

Comment: Can you change `if (id != null) {` to `if ($("#Locations").val() != null) {` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using JQuery $("#locations") to get the value? You could just use knockout to bind to a value in your viewmodel. Second, what is the trigger to reload? It's not clear from these code fragments

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what #locations refers to, but if it's a select list or something try this in the HTML (for example):

```
<select data-bind="value: locations">
  <option>location 1</option>
  <option>location 2</option>
<select>
```

And change the script:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // location will be stored here
    self.locations = ko.observable();

    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable();
    self.error = ko.observable();

    // we can avoid some repeat code:
    self.loadPosts = function () {
        // read value
        var id = self.locations();
        // set url and data
        var url = (id) ? postApiUrl2 : postApiUrl1;
        var data = (id) ? { id: id } : null;
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
    }

self.loadPosts();
return self;
```

Hope this helps.